# How do you make a conditional statement return true when only one condition is true?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I need to implement a functionality that takes a list of boolean values as input and returns true only if one of the conditions is true (if more, returns false). More formally, `f(c1, c2, c3 ... cN)` returns true if and only if **there's only one condition that evaluates true**, otherwise it returns false.

I implemented this method,

```
boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) {
    boolean retval = false;
    for (boolean c: conditions) {
        if (c) {
            if (!retval) {
                retval = true;
            } else {
                retval = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return retval;
}
```

but I'm asking for something more practical. I'm working with Java, but I think this problem is universal for every language. Thanks.

EDIT: The above example does the job very well, I'm only asking for a more practical way.

Comment: for (boolean condition : conditions) if (condition) return true

Comment: Sorry I didn't read well your question. You can just count the number of true condition, and return nbTrue == 1 ?

Comment: @kafjagjys, your code seems to be quite ok

Comment: What sort of solution would you consider more "practical"?

Answer (score 3):

A simple loop with a condition counting the `true` presence is a simple way to go The return statement is a comparison returning a `boolean`, whether the `true` count is qual exactly to 1:

```
long count = 0;
for (boolean condition: conditions) {
    if (condition) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count == 1;
```

This always iterates all the array which is not always necessary. You can optimize the iteration to stop when there are two `true` values found, hence it doesn't make sense to continue the iteration.

```
long count = 0;
for (boolean condition: conditions) {
    if (condition && ++count > 1) {
        break;
    }
}
return count == 1;
```

Comment: "_it's needed to iterate through all the array_" – Only true in the worst case (i.e. the last element is the first or second true value). Given the requirements, the algorithm can short-circuit immediately after the second true value is encountered.

Comment: @Slaw how can the algorithm  `"short-circuit immediately after the second true value is encountered"` ?

Comment: @RIVERMAN2010 The requirement is if the number of true values is `0` or `> 1` then the final result is `false`.  There's no reason to check for more than 2 true values because by then you know the final result is `false`.

Comment: @Slaw: Yes, you are right. I have fixed my mistake and added an optimization.

Comment: Btw, why use `long` for count?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Why not :) If you had asked me *"why not `int`"*, I'd have answered you *"why not `short`?"*. It depends...

Answer (score 3):

you could use this solution

```
public boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) {
         boolean m = false;
         for(boolean condition : conditions) {
             if(m && condition)
                 return false;
             m |= condition;
         }
         return m;
     }
```

this is a very small solution that does exactly what you want in very few lines.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I _think_ that ternary can be simplified to `m |= condition`.

Comment: @Slaw yes, you are correct it can be simplified, I will edit my answer

Answer (score 3):

Using Java Stream API:

```java
boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) {
    return IntStream.range(0, conditions.length)
        .filter(x -> conditions[x])  // leave only `true` values
        .limit(2)             // no need to get more than two
        .count() == 1;        // check if there is only one `true` value
}
```

Comment: Wrong on many levels! How this can be that heavily upvoted if it doesn't copile at all. 1) `conditions` vs `conditionals`. 2) `Arrays.stream(boolean[])` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis thanks for the feedback. The first point was a type, the second was me not realising that `Arrays.asStream(boolean[])` was missing. Seems strange but it is what it is, I suppose. Changed it to an `IntStream` with indexing the array. Not great IMO but it's the cheapest option.

Answer (score 0):

Using Stream API, you could rewrite it as (though it looks less "practical" as plain loop):

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

static boolean trueOnce(boolean ... conditions) {
    // find index of first true, if not available get -1
    int firstTrue = IntStream.range(0, conditions.length)
                             .filter(i -> conditions[i])
                             .findFirst().orElse(-1);

    // if first true is found, check if none in the remainder of array is true
    return firstTrue > -1 && IntStream.range(firstTrue + 1, conditions.length)
                                      .noneMatch(i -> conditions[i]);
}
```

---

Restoring initial version with a change suggested by @VLAZ:

```java
import java.util.stream.*;

boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) {
    return IntStream.range(0, conditions.length)
                    .filter(i -> conditions[i])
                    .limit(2) // !
                    .count() == 1;
}
```

Comment: This is very roundabout way of checking it. Doing `Arrays.stream(conditionals).filter(x -> x).limit(2).count()` will still use the Stream API and it's correct, short, readable.

Comment: Yes, limit(2)! :\

Answer (score 0):

An iteration can be performed using the while operator. A variable is defined to control the increments of positive values and another to evaluate each element of the array. These two variables will be our stop conditions and the method will return the solution, true for when there is a single positive value and false in all other cases.

```
boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) 
    {
        int i = 0, count = 0;
        
        while(count <= 1 && i < conditions.length){
            if(conditions[i++]){
                count++;
            }
        }
        
        return count == 1;
    }
```

or following the suggestion, we can use:

```
private static boolean trueOnce(boolean[] conditions) 
{
    int count = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < conditions.length && count <= 1; i++){
        if(conditions[i]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    
    return count == 1;
}
```

Comment: Using `while` loop with `i` is a bit verbose in this case :)